# Using URL Parameters in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url, parameters

I'm attempting to include url parameters in a link to my blog page.

I would like a link that looks like this:

```
/blog?data_cat_id=5&data_post_year=2014&data_post_month=5
```

I am able to construct the link the way I want it, either writing it out in plain text for testing purposes or generating it from variables in the WP loop. However, clicking on the link invariably goes to `/blog`, with the url parameters stripped off.

I have tried a couple things to get this to work.

**Strategy #1:**

I added the following function to my **functions.php** file to register the query parameters with WP.

```
function add_query_variables() {
    global $wp;
    $wp->add_query_var('data_cat_id');
    $wp->add_query_var('data_post_year');
    $wp->add_query_var('data_post_month');
}
add_filter('init', 'add_query_variables' );
```

This didn't work for a long while, and then started working after I went to **"Settings > Permalinks"** in the admin menu and clicked save (to clear the cached rewrite rules, just in case - I don't understand if they're involved here or not).

Everything was good, but then this **stopped** working when I removed a single query var from the above function that I no longer needed. (I originally also had `$wp->add_query_var('data_ajax_type');` in the above code.) Seriously, that is the only thing I changed.

I tried flushing the rewrite rule cache again, but nada, nothing. I tried adding that single should-be-irrelevant `$wp->add_query_var('data_ajax_type')` line back in. No dice. The url parameters are still being stripped when I click on my link.

**Strategy #2:**

When strategy #1 stopped working, I removed my `add_query_variables()` function from functions.php and tried using the `add_query_arg()` function to generate the link itself. (There has been no mention of needing to register query parameters with WP when using `add_query_arg()` in the articles/docs I have read, which is why I removed my `add_query_variables()` function. I don't know whether this is an oversight in the docs or if this is correct.)

My link is now being generated like this in my template file:

```
add_query_arg(
    array(
        'data_cat_id' => 5,
        'data_post_year' => 2014,
        'data_post_month' => 5
    ), '/blog'
)
```

The resulting link looks like this, which is what I want:

```
http://www.example.com/blog?data_cat_id=5&data_post_year=2014&data_post_month=5
```

But, once again, when I click on this link I wind up at `/blog`, with all of the url parameters stripped off.

So...I'm stuck on this one. I don't know what to do or what to try next. Any ideas, suggestions?

Any clarity on how these functions should be used in practice so that they actually work?

Comment: This is not standard behavior. I use URL parameters all the time with wordpress, and I cannot think of a single reason they are being stripped, unless there's some weird script doing it or something.

Comment: @Voltlight Do you use either of the above methods to include parameters in your URLs or do they just work automatically for you?

Comment: I've only ever used parameters for $_GET, as that's the only reason I imagine needing them. For example, with paypal responses etc. I've also used them for search filters, I don't ever have the problem of them disappearing or anything.